# Partial and exact match of strings in postgres

Tags: string, postgresql

I have following table in postgres 10.

```
col1        col2    col3                                            col4        
NCT00000102 Drug    nifedipine                                      nifed   
NCT00000102 Drug    nifedipine sulphate                             nifedipine  
NCT00000103 Drug    phospho nifedipine                              ni
NCT00000103 Drug    phospho nifedipine sulphate                     phospho nifedipine      
NCT00000105 Drug    fluticasone furoate (veramyst®) nasal spray     veramyst
NCT00000105 Drug    fluticasone furoate (veramyst®) nasal spray     vera
NCT00000106 Drug    veramyst                                        veramyst
```

I am looking for a way to filter above table so that either only exact match or partial match but with the complete word/s included.

I am expecting below output.

```
col1        col2    col3                                            col4        
NCT00000102 Drug    nifedipine sulphate                             nifedipine  
NCT00000103 Drug    phospho nifedipine sulphate                     phospho nifedipine      
NCT00000105 Drug    fluticasone furoate (veramyst®) nasal spray     veramyst
NCT00000106 Drug    veramyst                                        veramyst
```

I tried using below query but it is not giving me the partial matches properly.

```
where col3 '%' || col4 || '%'
```

Any suggestion here will be really useful.

Comment: Did you use `LIKE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using regex matching:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM yourTable
WHERE col3 ~* CONCAT('\y', col4, '\y');
```

This will return every record where the word or words in `col4` appear as proper word(s) in `col3`.  If you wanted to use `LIKE`, you could use:

```
WHERE col3 LIKE '%' || col4 || '%'
```

but keep in mind this might return false positives for substring matches.

Comment: WHERE col3 ~* '.*\y' || col4 || '\y.*'; gives below error: ERROR: argument of WHERE must be type boolean, not type text

Comment: `.*` in `.*\y`  will make it match slower. Remove `.*` from the regex as `~*` allows partial matches.

Comment: Does this where statement take only boolean. I am still getting this error.

Comment: @rshar Use `CONCAT` instead, or else you might need to do some casting.